# How to download artifacts using wget from Sonatype Nexus

Tags: linux, wget, nexus, sonatype

I got a Sonatype Nexus instance up and running and need to write a script to download a specific artifact manually.

I tried using the REST API and wget:

```
wget --user=username --password=password http://<ip>:<port>/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content?g=<group>&a=<artifact>&v=<version>&r=snapshots

Resolving <ip stuff>
Connecting to <ipv6 stuff>... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to <ipv4 stuff>... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Reusing existing connection to <ip>:<port>.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2014-05-11 20:17:01 ERROR 400: Bad Request.
```

Does anyone know, how to get this to work?

Edit: I'm able to download the artifact using my browser (and being logged in to the webinterface)

Answer (score 28):

The URL looks correct, but you're to have to quote it because it contains special characters.

```
wget --user=username --password=password "http://<ip>:<port>/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content?g=<group>&a=<artifact>&v=<version>&r=snapshots"
```

You also might want to add `--content-disposition` in order for the downloaded file name to be correct.  See here for more information:

https://support.sonatype.com/entries/23674267

Comment: is there one for powershell?  i got this on ps ,  Invoke-WebRequest : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '--password=admin123'.    here is the command:    wget --user=admin --password=admin123 "http://ec2-54-299-XX-231.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.
com:8081/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content?g=org&a=foo&v=1.0&r=releases"

Comment: Your Sonatype link is broken: `The page you were looking for doesn't exist`

Answer (score 2):

for nexus 3

```
wget --user=userid --password=password 'https://nexusurl:8081/nexus/repository/<repository id>/<replace the grouf is . with />/<artifact id>/<version>/<file name>' -O ${WORKSPACE}/<new file name>
```

example

group id =com.sap.cloudfoundry.mta_plugin_linux

artifact id =com.sap.cloudfoundry.mta_plugin_linux.api

nexus url = alm.xxxxxx.com

$WORKSPACE=jenkins present workspace

new filename=cf-cli-mta-plugin-2.0.3-linux-x86_64.bin

repository id = Sample_Replatform_Stage_2_Release (this you see as the name of the repo)

The command will be

```
 wget --user=USERID --password=PASSWORD 'https://alm.xxxxxxx.com/nexus/repository/sample_Replatform_Stage_2_Release/com/sap/cloudfoundry/mta_plugin_linux/com.sap.cloudfoundry.mta_plugin_linux.api/2.0.3/com.sap.cloudfoundry.mta_plugin_linux.api-2.0.3.bin' -O ${WORKSPACE}/cf-cli-mta-plugin-2.0.3-linux-x86_64.bin
```

**most importantly for nexus rest api the artifactID-version should always match the filename else you will get the maven2 repository format error**

for additional arguments and formats you may look in https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465488-How-can-I-retrieve-a-snapshot-if-I-don-t-know-the-exact-filename-

Answer (score 1):

GNU Wget 1.20.3 built on darwin19.0.0. goes like this:

```
wget --http-user myusername --http-password=mypassword https://nexus.example.com/myfile.zip
```